# Git Flow Feature to branch Develop when Feature it was based off doesn't exist anymore

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I got myself into a small bit of a pickle.

I accidentally based a feature (let's call it A) off another feature (let's call it B) instead of the develop branch. In the meantime, feature A was completed and merged to develop.

Now I want to finish feature B, but I'm getting the following error on Sourctree

> Fatal: The base 'feature/A' doesn't exists locally or is not a branch.
> Can't finish the feature branch 'feature/B'.

I've tried: `git rebase --onto develop feature/B`

But this only removed the changes from B and pushed develop on the branch, I'm lucky my remote picked it up and I was able to pull/sync the changes I had on remote to restore what was on B.

Is there any way I could come back from this? To somehow change the reference that B was based on A to say that B is based off develop (that already contains A)?

:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sourcetree, if you navigate to Settings -> Edit Config File (open in Notepad), you can change:

```
[gitflow "branch.feature/B"]
    base = branch.feature/A
```

to:

```
[gitflow "branch.feature/B"]
    base = develop
```

Which will then allow you to finish the feature on branch develop (just get ready for any potential conflicts. In my case I had none since feature A was already in the develop branch)

Just make sure you don't mistakenly base a feature off another feature like I did!

Comment: You can also find the config file at `{<repo root>/.git/config}`

Answer (score 1):

Rebase will work fine, but you have to tell it *also* which revisions to skip from rebase. If the branch is gone, use the last revision ID of the base branch below your branch (which can be seen with a simple `git log`):

```
git rebase --onto develop id-last-revision-of-A feature/B
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found another resource that mentioned something about the config file. I was able to edit the config file (Settings -> Edit Config File in Sourcetree) and change the "base = " setting in B to reference develop instead of A, the merge was successful :)