# Git check for child branch

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm working with git flow and trying to setup an automation for start/finish branches.

imagine that I create a feature_1 based on develop branch,

```bash
$ <develop> git flow feature start feature_1
```

than someone creates a feature_1_a based on feature_1

```bash
$ <feature/feature_1> git flow feature start feature_1_a feature/feature_1
```

If I finish feature_1, feature_1_a cannot be finished:

```
Fatal: The base 'feature/feature_1' doesn't exists locally or is not a branch. 
Can't finish the feature branch 'feature/feature_1_a'.
```

before I finish feature_1, is that a way to tell that there is a "child" branch based on it? also i'd like to show that feature_1_a/b/n is based on feature_1.

Comment: *Git* does not have or support parent/child relationships with branch names. Git-flow might, but that's a Git-flow thing at that point. (How Git-flow could manage this is not clear to me, what with branch names in Git being ephemeral and mostly irrelevant...)

Comment: After finishing the first branch you just need to manually change the second one to be based off of `develop`. Does this answer your question? [Git Flow Feature to branch Develop when Feature it was based off doesn't exist anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67293367/git-flow-feature-to-branch-develop-when-feature-it-was-based-off-doesnt-exist-a)

Comment: Side Note: when I first started using Git Flow I tried out the commands, but in just a few days I decided to just do what those commands do myself, since you have a little more control when you wish to tweak something, kind of like what happened here in this question.